# Call send method from command link

Tags: javascript, apex-email-service, commandlink

I have a send method outside constructor in apex class. I need to call that from Command button onclick. Can someone help me here?

Send method:

```
public PageReference send() {
        String addresses;
        // Define the email
        Messaging.SingleEmailMessage email = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage(); 

        // Reference the attachment page and pass in the account ID
        PageReference pdf =  Page.VF_IncidentDetail_PDF3;
        pdf.getParameters().put('id',(String)recId); //
        pdf.setRedirect(true);//false

        // Take the PDF content
        Blob b = pdf.getContent();

        // Create the email attachment
        Messaging.EmailFileAttachment efa = new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment();
        efa.setFileName('attachment.pdf');
        efa.setBody(b); 
        addresses = 'spandan@bbb.com';


       // if (account.Contacts[0].Email != null) {}
        addresses += ':' + 'anilkumar.lingaraju@abbvie.com'+':'+'tumpu1985@gmail.com'+':'+'saikat.neogy@cognizant.com' ;
        String[] toAddresses = addresses.split(':', 0);

        // Sets the paramaters of the email
        email.setSubject( 'Incident Details');
        email.setToAddresses( toAddresses );
        email.setPlainTextBody( body );

        email.setFileAttachments(new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment[] {efa});        // Sends the email
        Messaging.SendEmailResult [] r = 
            Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] {email});   

        return pdf;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can call the send method with the following in your VF page .

```
 <apex:commandButton action="{!send}" value="Send" id="theButton"/>
```

For more information pls refer to this link http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_commandButton.htm